# How to sort by nested value where non-nested field matches another nested field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to sort results by `Groups.CategoryPriority` but filter the groups so that it sorts only by the groups where `Groups.ParentGroupId` matches  `PrimaryParentGroupId`.

The following does not work (ignore the double quotes, their are needed in C# for multiline strings):

```
""sort"": [
    {
        ""Groups.CategoryPriority"": {
            ""order"": ""asc""
            ,""nested_path"": ""Groups""  
            ,""nested_filter"": { 
                ""match"": {
                    ""Groups.ParentGroupId"": ""PrimaryParentGroupId"" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

My Product document model example:

```
{
    "Id":1,
    "PrimaryParentGroupId" : 1,
    "PrimaryGroupId" : 2
    "Groups":[
        {
            "Id":1,
            "ParentGroupId" : 1,
            "CategoryPriority":2
        },
        {
            "Id":2,
            "ParentGroupId" : 3,
            "CategoryPriority":1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you mean that you still want that document in the list but for sort you want to filter. maybe script can help you

Comment: @user3775217 exactly. How would I do this with script?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting